# send each request to appropriate controller

Tags: php, model-view-controller, controller, bootstrapping

I want to make a small web application, and I'm not sure how to go about this.
What I want to do is send every request to the right controller. Kind of how CodeIgniter does it.

So if user asks for domain.com/video/details
I want my bootstrap (index?) file to send him to the "Video" controller class and call the "details" method in that class.

If the user asks for domain.com/profile/edit I want to send him to the "Profile" controller class and call the "edit" method in that class.

Can someone explain how I should do this? I have some experience using MVC frameworks, but have never "written" something with MVC myself.

Thanks!

**Edit: I understand now how the url points to the right Controller, but I don't see where the object instance of the Controller is made, to call the right method?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use mod-rewrite (.htaccess) to
   rewrite the url from
   www.example.com/taco to
   www.example.com/index.php?taco/
2. in index.php, grab the first URL
   parameter key, use that to route to
   the correct url. As it will look
   like "taco/"
3. You may want to add / to the front
   and back if it doesn't exist. As
   this will normalize the urls and
   make life easier
4. If you want to preserve the ability
   to have traditional query strings.
   Inspect the URL directly and take
   the query string portion. break that
   on ?, which will leave you with the
   routing info in key 0 and the rest
   in key 1. split that on &, then
   split each of those on = and set the
   first to the key and the second to
   the value of an array. Replace $_GET
   with that array.

Example:

```
$path = explode("?", $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"],2);
$url = $path[0];
if(substr($url,0,1) != "/")
{
    $url = "/".$url;
}
if(substr($url,-1,1) != "/")
{
    $url = $url."/";
}
unset($_GET);
foreach(explode("&", $path[1]) as $pair)
{
    $get = explode("=", $pair, 2);
    $_GET[$get[0]] = $get[1];
}

// Define the Query String Path
define("QS_PATH", $url);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-route your requests.  Using apache, this can be done using mod_rewrite.

For example, add a .htaccess file to your public base directory and add the following:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will redirect users trying to access

> /profile/edit

to

> index.php?rt=profile/edit

In index.php, you can access the **$_GET['rt']** to determine which controller and action has been requested.

Comment: And how do I call the actuall method? I have to make some kind of object instance out of the controller, right?

Comment: You would have to build a class around the controller.  Typically, the index.php file will dissect the request string and pass the parameters to the controller object.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do or how much work you want to do, another option versus writing your own MVC is to use Zend Framework.  It does exactly what you're asking for and more.  You still need to configure URL rewriting as mentioned in the other answers, but it quick and easy.

Even if you're not interested in Zend Framework, the following link can help you configure your rewrite rules: http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV/Configuring%2BYour%2BURL%2BRewriter

Comment: I actually do plan on using the Zend Framework, but I'd like to understand how MVC exactly works. Altough the answers have been useful so far, I still don't quite understand how the exact Controller and the right method is called.